# Kotlin / Java - Interface implementation + Inheritance

Tags: java, kotlin, inheritance, interface

I have the following classes and interface:

```
class A() {
    fun one() {...}
    fun two() {...}
}

class B(): A, C {
    fun tree() {...}
}

interface C {
    fun one()
    fun two()
    fun tree()
}
```

As you can class B extends A and also implements interface C.
The problem is that in Kotlin class B which is the actual implementor of C does not have the 2 first funcs and therefore not implementing the right functions for the interface.
Is there a right way to do such thing?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? Class A's implementations of  `one` and `two` satisfy the interface contract. If you want to override them, you need to mark the functions `open` in class A. And of course, class A itself must be marked open for your above code to compile.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I dont wanna override them, I want them to satisfy the interface but that's not the case. I'm getting `Class 'B' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun one()`

Answer (score 1):

1. The `A` class needs to be marked `open`.
2. The super class `A` of the class `B` needs to be initialized (i.e. `A()`)
3. The `B.tree()` method requires `override` modifier

Apart of that, it should work...

```kotlin
open class A {
    fun one() {}
    fun two() {}
}

class B: A(), C {
    override fun tree() {}
}

interface C {
    fun one()
    fun two()
    fun tree()
}
```